# how to install ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows7 ultimate

Tags: xubuntu

6 months ago I formatted my 320GB hard disk drive and changed the partition table to GPT, then I installed windows 8.1. With gparted I formated my whole hard disk and changed the partition table to MSDOS. Then I installed windows 7 ultimate.

After that I started to install ubuntu 14.04 but there was no option to install along side my windows 7. I didn't pay attention and I selected something else. I made 30 GB partition for Ubuntu and 3 GB for swap with gparted. All the things went well but when I started the lap top again it was only Uuntu booting and there wasn't any option to choose windows booting. It seemed that windows is not installed.

Then I again formated my HDD and installed windows 7. Now I want to install ubuntu but still facing the same problem. There is no option to install along side windows 7. Ubuntu doesn't recogniz my os. I tried sudo os-prober but it answers nothing.
Now I installed windows 7.

What should I do to install ubuntu alongside it ? I do really love ubuntu? Sorry for my bad english. With special thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Ubuntu expert, but I've had the same problem as you and that is probably a quick fix.

When you installed Ubuntu along side your Windows 7. Windows did not disappear, it was still there. The problem is that Ubuntu boot system overwrote the Windows boot, but did not uninstalled it!

So, for you to get a dual boot on your PC startup, you need do enter the fresh installed Ubuntu and download grub2 [Ubuntu Wiki: Reinstalling GRUB2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2)

After that, restart your PC and you should get a screen on system startup that let's you choose if you want to boot Ubuntu or Windows.